# What is the entire folder structure to create magento 2 admin grid?

Tags: magento2, module, grid, custom

What is the entire folder structure to create a custom admin grid?

example -

vendor_name : Ayakil

module_name : Rewardpoints

I am expecting like this.

[image]

Why i am asking this question is , i am unable to figure out what is my issue during custom grid developing.

And here why we are using **di.xml**

**Kindly notice that my entire module code is inside the vendor_name folder.**

Comment: you should probably follow this tutorial : https://webkul.com/blog/create-grid-edit-add-grid-row-and-installer-in-magento2/

Comment: its easy to use UiComponent Grid instead of block